# Using Google Docs with Trello

Tags: google-drive, trello

I use Trello to upload blog articles so my team can see them, and select who will edit which post. Instead of uploading Word files from various computers, is there a way we could use Google Docs and Trello combined? Since I like the collaborative aspect of Google Docs for editing and I like Trello to organize who on the team is editing what and what phase in editing is a certain blog post. Any help on how I can incorporate the two?

Comment: How about just the link to the respective doc?

Answer (score 5):

There are two great Google Docs with scripts for working with Trello.

One for importing into Trello from Google Docs:
http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/blog/online-scrum-tools-part-3-upload-existing-product-backlog-into-trello/

And another for backing up all your Trello boards and cards to Google Docs:
http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/blog/online-scrum-tools-part-4-trello-backup/

So you can use these in tandem to manage your Trello boards from Google Docs.

Answer (score 3):

We've started attaching Google Docs to every card for developers to write notes, and testers to write test scripts - It was a pain to do manually so I created a script that will add docs to all existing cards, [and automatically add them to new cards as they are created](http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/pimp-your-trello-cards/):

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature built in to Trello, but adding a link to the Google Doc in the description or in a comment should work well.